# listpicker selectionchanged not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am attempting to choose a specific item upon the selectionchanged event of the ListPicker for WP7. I believe I have implemented the ListPicker properly and have binded an array of text to the ListPicker, but my issue arises when attempting to select a specific item in the ListPicker. My ListPicker is in my SettingsPage.xaml and I would like to pass a certain string to my MainPage.xaml object for use there. My code is as follows

SettingsPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="SearchProviderItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SearchProvider}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Title="QUEST">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="browser">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentPanel_Browser" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    ...

                    <!-- Search Provider -->
                    <TextBlock Text="Search provider" Margin="12,7,12,8"
                       Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>
                    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="SearchProviderListPicker" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="12,0,12,0"  
                                        ItemTemplate="{Binding SearchProviderItemTemplate}" 
                                        SelectionChanged="SearchProviderListPicker_SelectionChanged" />
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>                
            <!--<Grid/>-->
        </controls:PivotItem>
```

SettingsPage.xaml.cs

```
    string searchProvider;

    String[] SearchProvider = 
    {
        "Google", 
        "Bing",
        "Yahoo",
        "Ask",
        "AOL"
    };


    private void SearchProviderListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.AddedItems.Equals("Google"))
        {
            searchProvider = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";
        }
        else if(e.AddedItems.Equals("Bing"))
        {
            searchProvider = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=";
        }


        //if (SearchProvider.Equals("Google"))
        //{
        //    searchProvider = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";
        //}
        //else if(SearchProvider.Equals("Bing"))
        //{
        //    searchProvider = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=";
        //}

    }        

    public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SearchProviderListPicker.ItemsSource = SearchProvider;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        //Send searchProvider to MainPage.xaml
        if (searchProvider != null)
        {
            //this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?curProvider=" + searchProvider, UriKind.Relative));
            NavigationContext.Equals("curProvider=" + searchProvider);
        }            
    }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
string _searchProvider;

//OnNavigatedTo method
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        //for Search Provider (from SettingsPage.xaml)
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("curProvider", out _searchProvider);


    }

private void SearchBar_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string search;
        string _search = SearchBar.Text;
        search =  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_search);

        //search whats in the searchbar
        //use inputscope enter key to start search!
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            //check to ensure absolute navigation uri, else search through bing?
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search)) 
                return;
            if (search.Equals("about:blank")) 
                return;

            if (_searchProvider != null)
            {                  
                TheBrowser.Navigate(_searchProvider + search);
            }

            //Google
            //TheBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + search);

            //Bing
            //TheBrowser.Navigate("http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + search);

            //Yahoo
            //TheBrowser.Navigate("http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + search);

            //Ask
            //TheBrowser.Navigate("http://www.ask.com/web?q=" + search);

            //AOL
            //TheBrowser.Navigate("http://search.aol.com/search?q=" + search);


            //lose focus of textbox while navigating
            this.Focus();
        }
    }
```

essentially I would like to pass the selected ListPicker item to the MainPage so that it may be used as the default search provider of a webbrowser control. Any ideas on how this may be implemented? Any code assistance would be greatly appreciated.. I am really unsure of how to quite accomplish this correctly (as of now I do not have any debugging or runtime errors but the webbrowser does not search when attempting to use the selected ListPicker item)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `AddedItems` returns a list of selected items. Doing a direct `Equals("somestring")` will not work. You'll have get the specific item object and them try to use a comparision.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the selected item.

```
private void SearchProviderListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedItem = e.AddedItems[0] as string; //I'm not sure, whether it'll be string. Please check the type of objects in the list. But the logic will be the same.
        if(selectedItem == "Google")
        {
            searchProvider = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";
        }
        else if(selectedItem == "Bing")
        {
            searchProvider = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=";
        }
        //Continue the comparison

    }
```

Comment: thanks @Amresh Kumar, i added some code to yours above that I believe fixes an IndexOutOfRangeException. Any ideas on how to pass this selected string value to my MainPage without 'navigate'?

Comment: @Matthew To pass back the value, you have to pass it in query string. Or you can use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings to save the value. The IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings stores K-V pairs, and can be accessed throughout the application.

Comment: Thanks @Amresh Kumar I used the query string method and it works great, but I did realize that after I pick the provider I want and then navigate back to MainPage, if i chose to go back to SettingsPage again my listbox shows the first provider in the ListPicker index instead of the one that is actually currently being used (say for instance I chose Bing and it is being used but ListPicker still says Google). What would you recommend as to always displaying the current provider in the listpicker?

Comment: @Matthew The best approach will be to use IsolatedStorage. So whether you are in MainPage or Settings page, you can get the current provider. So when you select a new provider you save the new value back to IsolatedStorage. And in your SettingsPage you can get back the selected provider and set the selectedIndex of listpicker to the corresponding value.

Comment: Thanks @Amresh Kumar. I attempted the following but the selectedIndex does not show the current search provider properly. I can set 'SelectedIndex="0"' for Google in the xaml but in the code behind after Bing search provider is chosen 'SearchProviderListPicker.SelectedIndex="1" has no effect on changing the shown search provider in the list picker?

Comment: @Matthew You can refer http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Working-with-WP7-ListPicker-SelectedItem for the ListPicker selected item/index property.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListPickerItem Item = SearchProviderListPicker.SelectedItem as ListPickerItem;
 string type = Item.Content.ToString();
```

Gets the item string.